# Correct usage of cache-control header for api

Tags: php, caching, http-headers

For improved client-side caching of a web api (used as backend of a mobile application), I want to make use of cache-control headers. All data is served via https-get requests as json strings and is not user-specific. So if user A makes a request and user B makes the same, they get the exact same data.

Im kinda new to this caching stuff and just want to ask if I get things right. Lets say I want to advise clients to cache a response for 10 minutes, is it correct to set the headers in this way?

```
cache-control: public, max-age=600
expires: <current server time + 600s>
```

Also, I'm not sure if its a good idea to set `must-revalidate` in this specific use case. From what I understand, User-agents might serve outdated data in some circumstance (like a bad internet connection on mobile devices). This is prevented by setting `must-revalidate` (If max-age is expired, dont serve outdated data at any circumstance). Is this right? In this case I wouldn't use it because serving outdated data would be better then having no data at all.